# Why was this answer marked as "spam or rude or abusive?"

Tags: discussion

It seems unremarkable to me.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/revisions/183046/1

Question:
[Invitation to a new conference: possible scam?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/183027/invitation-to-a-new-conference-possible-scam/183046#183046)

Comment: This particular site spams us a lot. If you see links to this site please report them, as they are likely also spam.

Comment: @BryanKrause That's probably the answer I was looking for.  The marking might have been caused by a pattern of behavior I cannot see.

Answer (score 8):

Because it is spam.

The included link contains referral information that can be used to track the origin of the link visits, and maybe reward the author.

On a general note, sometimes spam may not be so evident from a single post, and normal users might be puzzled by certain deletions, but it becomes evident when there is a pattern of posts linking to the same website.

Comment: +1. Just to add that this seems like a rare case where we could have salvaged the answer by removing the last paragraph; however, there is an SE-wide policy/guideline that one should [never edit spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited).

Comment: I don't think "utm_campaign=editage--academia_stackexchange" is sufficient to make something spam.  If some company's marketing department wants to pay people to post sensible answers, that's not spam.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Undisclosed affiliation to a linked company website is spam.

Comment: The top voted answer in this meta question disagrees with you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist This is not StackOverflow. But if in doubt, it's fine to raise a custom flag if you are wondering if a post is self promotional.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist See https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/promotion "However, if you mention your product, website, etc. in your question or answer, you must disclose your affiliation in your post"

Comment: This is not stack overflow but this is quite similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist From the answer to the faq you linked: "Lacks disclosure of affiliation means that the author is clearly affiliated with the product but does not disclose their affiliation. Note that a simple “my” may suffice. However, the disclosure must happen in the post itself; the author’s username or profile do not count".

Comment: And, to be honest, i don't understand the purpose of your discussion: do you want more spam on Academia?

Comment: I don't think you've read the link carefully.  I think Bran Krause gave a much clearer explanation than you did; namely that there is a history of spam linking to this "Editage" site.  Your viewpoint seems exceptionally arbitrary.

Comment: "A post should be marked as spam only if it **promotes** a product, service, or similar; ***and* is unsolicited *or* lacks disclosure of affiliation.**" The given post meets this criteria, ergo it is spam. That it has happened regularly makes  deletion more justified, but is not required; doing it once is still spamming.