# Why is this particular question closed as rude?

Tags: discussion

Why was

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/184049

> marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown

I can see closing it as off topic for this stackexchange site but I think calling it "spam or rude or abusive" is rude to the OP.

Comment: See my answer here, the last paragraph: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5139 Mods have a wider view of certain users' behaviour, and when we nuke as spam or rude, it's because there's more evidence.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I saw that other answer. Of course I couldn't (and shouldn't) know about the other evidence. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making Massimo's comment into an answer:

> Mods have a wider view of certain users' behavior, and when we nuke as spam or rude, it's because there's more evidence.

We can't comment on this case in particular, but I will provide another data point in general. Just this morning, a few of us mods were discussing a different question that we felt should be closed as too broad, but we ended up not taking any action (even though 2+ moderators agreed!) because mod votes are binding, and we hesitate to take that sort of action unilaterally. You can imagine, therefore, that we apply a correspondingly greater degree of care when it comes to "nuking" questions entirely.

Comment: "We can't comment on this case in particular" really needs more explanation.  I think you can make some kind of abstract statement that actually answers Ethan's question.

Comment: The "abstract statement" is that we do not nuke things for no reason; there must be more evidence. It is SO policy not to discuss this evidence, however.